# Getting the string between two equal signs

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Python's RE to get information that is between two equal signs (`=helloThere=`) but not what's between more than a single equal sign (`==helloThere==`).

This is what I came up with so far but it's not doing it:

```
result = re.findall('={1}(.*?)={1}', text)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!=)=([^=]+)=(?!=)', '=hello there=')
['hello there']
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!=)=([^=]+)=(?!=)', '==hello there==')
[]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only those two conditions:

1 - Starts and Ends with `=` 
2 - There should be only two `=`

Then this is my suggestion to you:

```
s = '=helloThere='
test_char = '='
if (s[0] == s[-1] == test_char) and s.count('=') == 2:
    print(s[1:-1])
    # or print(s.strip('=')
```

This is valid if the expression between `=` does not contain another `=`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for something I'd use with findall since the input string is very long and I want to find multiple occurrences of this pattern.

Comment: Yea, a regular expression is the way to go in your case, with my solution you will have to wrap it in a for loop, with calculating loop steps, which will add more complications that's already been handled by regular expression.